# How does Polaris remain constant for millennia if the earth is spinning, orbiting and traveling with the galaxy?

Tags: fundamental-astronomy

Look at Polaris. Understand heliocentric theory and then reason.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth's orientation doesn't change that much to observe visible changes in a lifetime. Because its distance is that big we will see no difference in the summer position and winter position. It moving ineed but this motion is again too small to be observed in a lifetime.

Comment: Are you kidding me?...500,000 mph for millennia and no change?...1000 mph "rotation", 67,000 mph "orbit", and 500,000 mph forward travel and Polaris has remained constant with all of that allegedly happening?...stunning, just stunning

Comment: Polaris *does* move. Per the [Simbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fbasic) entry, it has an annual parallax of 7.5 milli-arcseconds (due to the Earth's motion about the Sun) and a proper motion of about 46 milli-arcsec per year (dut to the combination of its motion in the Galaxy and the Sun's motion in the Galaxy).

Comment: @TerribleAvenger Polaris is about 2,500,000,000,000,000 (2.5 quadrillion) miles away. That's why you can't see it move with the human eye. (But we *can* see it move with high-precision telescopes.)

Comment: So you "geniuses" think that the "galaxy" is moving away from Polaris, for billions of years, while the earth is spinning at 1000 mph, orbiting at 67k mph, traveling at 500k mph and every other star has kept the exact trajectory for thousands of years to appear not to move any?..........Y'all ever heard of Dunning-Kruger Syndrome?...There aren't enough Asians in all of Asia to do that math.... Dumbest generation ever...Hey, I have this investment. A secret Tesla teleportation stick. Only $999.99 but y'all can have it 50% off...

Comment: @TerribleAvenger Whit's the Dunning Kruger sindrum?

Comment: Dunning and Kruger did a study on folks...basically it explained why stupid people don't know that they're stupid. They knew just enough about a subject to be confident and arrogant, but when questioned they were horribly wrong.  No critical thinking ability. No ability to say, WTF? Dunning-Kruger goes hand in hand with the Milgram Experiment...except the numbers are probably higher today. We live in the dumbest generation ever. So proud of ourselves for all of our "advancements". Congratulating ourselves for how smart we are. Too stupid to realize how stupid we really are.

Comment: @TerribleAvenger But what has this got to do with the questions asked here? Or the answers given?

Comment: The answers given are not in the realm of possibility. In fact, they're so improbable, the math even says, "are you fucking kidding me?"...the "theory" is an ever expanding Universe...it's not plausible Polaris remains constant AND the constellations. Not over billions of years. It doesn't stand up to reason. It's like y'all told reason to go fuck itself...it's stunning.

Comment: @TerribleAvenger But they dont remain the same. All constellations change ver slowly. But not so much that you can see it within a lifetime. Once in a while a big flash occurs. And even the dun smiles once in a while.

Comment: Sure, you stick with that...they've remained unchanged for all of recorded history. 1 yr is over 4 trillion miles squared...that's all galaxies...and they're spinning, orbiting and wobbling...

Comment: @TerribleAvenger It cant be denied that rocking and rolling is goin on. There are even Sex Pistols songs to be heard up there.5ut there are also pieces of Satie played. Or even 4 minutes of quiet.

Comment: @TerribleAvenger ♩

Comment: Thanks for playing... math is hard.

Comment: @TerribleAvenger Just a bunch of numbers tied together. Even imaginary ones...

Comment: Cognitive Dissonance is rough...studying the stars and never coming to those conclusions has to be tough. Ever wondered why the big dipper rotates with the seasons?...shouldn't it be on the opposite side of the sun from summer to winter?...its a simple observation...☝️

Comment: @TerribleAvenger Why it should be on the opposite sides when seen in winter and summer?

Comment: @TerribleAvenger Ah you mean on opposite sides of the sun? Yes in winter it is seen by night and in summer by day (or something in between).

Comment:   wow...wow...